# My take on creating a notification system in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, mailboxer

I can't find any conclusive articles showing how to create notifications in rails. Everyone seems to talk about Mailboxer like it's a good solution, but other than the one paragraph they have on the :Notify method, it seems very vague.

So I'm thinking of creating a notification model which belongs to Activity (Public Activity Gem) and then using an after_create callback on the activity model to call a notify method which then calls the notify method of the activities object in question.

As a diagram

```
    class Comment
    include PublicActivity::Model
      tracked

    def notify
          #Loop through all involved users of this modal instance and create a Notify record pointing to the public activity
        end
    end

    class Activity < PublicActivity::Activity # (I presume I can override the gems Activity model in my App?)
    after_create :notify

      private
        def notify
          #Call the notify function from the model referenced in the activity, in this case, comment
        end
    end
```

So when the comment modal is called, public activity tracks it which then calls back the comments notify method to save in a Notify model

Notify model would simply consist of

```
user_id, activity_id, read:boolean
```

Note: I am trying my best to keep everything out of the controller, as I think the whole thing would be better handled in the model. But I'm open to suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a Notification model with required fields. And if you want to notify an admin every time a user has done any Activity(a new entry in Activity Model), you can create the notification in the after_create method on the Activity model.

```
class Activity
  after_create :notify

  def notify
    n = Notification.create(user_id: self.user_id, activity_id: self.id)
    n.save
  end
end
```

The above code will create an entry in the notification table for new Activity creation, with the activity id and the user id.

More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25290179/5027587).